# VMware vCenter and ESXi monitoring with Xymon

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, xymon

We currently have a Windows vCenter for which I have written a few scripts for various monitoring with Xymon.

We are moving to a vCenter Appliance and I need to port these scripts (or write equivalent new scripts) to work on the vCenter and the ESXi hosts.

Can I get the Xymon client installed on an ESXi host (I suspect I need to add that as a plan after each upgrade too) or is there an alternative way?

I understand there are better monitoring solutions out there than Xymon, but we use this and migrating isn't an option right now.

Comment: I don't feel like pasting my script as an answer and URLs as answers are frowned so here it is in a comment. It uses SSH from the XYMon server via RSA Auth and PYVMOMI. https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/ESXi++6+-+Ram+-+CPU+-+Disk+Check+-+NTP+-+XYMon+-+Ubuntu

Comment: Too many redirects - fails to open

Comment: Have you been to my site in the past? I'm wondering if an old 301 is in your cache. Try a different browser as well, but thank you for letting me know!

Comment: Works in a different browser. Checking it out. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe I have, but there is always a chance I have I guess

Comment: OK, so i am getting "Could not connect to the specified host using the specified username and password" confirmed they are correct.

Comment: That sounds like an ESXi SSH issue, can you SSH to the host from the CLI? Forget about the script until that's working.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of options to get data out of vcenter for xymon.

### You can not install xymon-clinet on esx, and must use scripts to get data via API / PowerCLI

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xymonesxi/
Xymon Monitor for Vmware ESXi

http://www.squidworks.net/2012/11/xymon-esx-hardware-health-monitor/

xymon scripts and implementation stuff

```
Creators of pyVmomi :
```

See github

“pyVmomi is the Python SDK for the VMware vSphere API that allows you to manage ESX, ESXi, and vCenter.”

```
Creator of python-vmstats :
```

also github /python-vmstats

“Python script using pyVmomi to get VM statistics”

I hope this helps.